# View sysextendedarticlesview

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know what this view is for? Its obviously system generated and I have found it in 2 of my replicated databases but not in others.

Answer (score 0):

> View sysextendedarticlesview
>
> Does anyone know what this view is for?

[The sysextendedarticlesview view provides information about published articles. This view is stored in the distribution database.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-views/sysextendedarticlesview-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Why would this appear in a user database? I deleted it as a test but was forced to recreate it has it broke replication on that database. As I said, it only appears in 2 of my replicated databases, not all.

Comment: Views are created in a user database when that database is enabled as a publication or subscription database. Are you sure all databases are set up exactly the same in Replication?

Comment: I thought it had something to do with replication settings but so far can't find any differences (apart from published articles).

Comment: Are all databases distributed databases on that server where you have the replication system views? I would expect those two databases with the view to be distributed on that server and the rest to not be.

Comment: There are no replicated views in the publication. I'm wondering if somebody tried adding one at some point then backed out leaving this system view behind.